# IN operator of datastore JPA Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

IN operator of Datastore JDO referenced in this document https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Filters

So, in Datastore JPA what is it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Errm, an "IN" operator in JPA is called "IN", as per the JPA2 spec. The JPA spec would be recommended reading, together with the DataNucleus v3.x docs.

JDO has no "IN" operator (as that doc tells you clearly), it has "contains". GAE/Datastore has the "IN" operator referred to in that page